# How to solve include_once() Warnings in tmp directory after migration?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, fatal-error, jerror

After Joomla migration, I'm left with a few errors like:

> Warning: include_once(menu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/doc/www.elody.cz/www/tmp/htmlpaUI9p on line 1
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'menu.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /www/doc/www.elody.cz/www/tmp/htmlpaUI9p on line 1

The `/tmp/` folder is empty, the cache is empty and turned off.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

These are not Errors, these are only Warnings (or is there also any error message connected to these particularly?). This warning usually happens when (due to ie. migration) a file path was changed and the ROOT or BASE path is different than it was before. in Joomla in 'Admin->Global configuration' if you set 'Error Reporting' to 'system default', then these warnings are not visible to your visitors (and otherwise the warnings do not cause problems in the site operations most of the times, however sometimes can cause fatal error too). Possible solutions:

1. After migration maybe in your **configuration.php** file the **live_site** variable is wrongly defined. You should check that and should be set to the correct value (usually an empty string ''). Also check the **$tmp_path** variable's value in this same file.
2. If the first is OK (and the file path warning is still there), then in your template's **index.php** file you might want to add the following (at the top of the file):

   ```
   <?php
       $this->baseurl = JPATH_BASE;
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you don't yet have your file path properly declared.

I'll offer some instructions to correct your `tmp` path, but you should execute the same technique to eliminate the other Warnings too.

### If you have access to your administrator backend:

Go to  **System** > **Global Configuration** > **Server** (tab).
The **Path to Temp Folder** field should read something like `/home/htmlpaUI9p/public_html/temp`

### If you don't yet have access to your administrator backend:

Go to your **configuration.php** file which should be inside your **htmlpaUI9p** directory.
Change the line with `public $tmp_path` to `public $tmp_path = '/home/htmlpaUI9p/public_html/tmp';`

---

If this advice doesn't work as desired, please update your question with what occurs after the change and any other valuable details that will help us to help you.